# Convert text to image in centos from bash

Tags: linux, text-processing, conversion

I want to create an image [jpg, png, doesn't matter] from shell but I don't have convert command. The image is very simple - white background with a medium-size black text in the middle. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you do not have the `convert` tool, install [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org) (this is where `convert` comes from). You'll certainly have it in your distro's repositories. As you mentioned the tool, I assume you already know how to create such image with it.